# Manipulating oembeds in django

Tags: html, css, django, oembed, django-oembed

I'm using the django-oembed app to embed (among other content) some flickr photos: Using this:

```
 {% oembed %} http://www.flickr.com/photos/majdal/3866163776/ {% endoembed %}
```

will return this:

```
<img alt="Basilica di San Giorgio Maggiore" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2429/3866163776_3e63cc9b49.jpg">
```

This is excellent, except that I need to add a rounded corner mask to the photo. I know I can do that if the image was a background to a , but that's not possible with the output of the {% oembed %} tag. Any ideas on what else could work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the `oembed` tag result with a `DIV` element and apply styles to that:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.oembed img {
        border: #fafafa 3px solid;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
</style>

<div class="oembed">
    {% oembed %}  {{ image_url }} {% endoembed %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! this actually works in both Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox. I used -moz-border-radius: 5px; but that still doesn't work.